# php mvc joomla Component loader error

Tags: php, model-view-controller, joomla1.5

I create folder in local server and copy other site's joomla system files in this folder. after when i login administrator page there is error: "Component loader error". how can i improve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Which joomla version? Which operating system? Have you double-checked your installation procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of you do not change the configuration.php file with your local server related setting.

did you download DB from server as well?

I think you are missing DB.